# What are the valid formats for numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax

What are the valid formats are for numbers in MATLAB? The following seem to be valid:

```
x=0;
x=0.;
x=0.0;
x=0e0;
x=0E0;
x=0000.00; % Trailing and leading zeros seem to be irrelevant
```

Are there other valid general number specifications? I can't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the regex of floating-point number formats, valid in MATLAB:

```
^[-+]*([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*)([eEdD][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Compiled from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html), and slightly modified for MATLAB:

- added `'d'` exponent character (as is common in FORTRAN, MATLAB's ancestor)
- added uppercase exponent characters
- added extra case in the required order before and after the decimal symbol

I'm pretty sure the *locale* can mess this up, e.g., the decimal separator `.` might be set to `,` as is common here in Europe. Oh well.

The regex in words:

- string start, followed by
- zero or more consecutive sign symbols, followed by

  - non-zero length string of consecutive integers, OR
  - possibly zero-length string of consecutive integers, followed by a dot, followed by non-zero length string of consecutive integers, OR
  - non-zero length string of consecutive integers, followed by a dot, followed by a possibly zero-length string of consecutive integers
- optionally followed by the exponent part:

  - one of `e`, `E`, `d` or `D`.
  - zero or one sign symbols, followed by
  - non-zero length string of consecutive integers
- followed by string terminator

Note that this is for *non-complex* floating point values. For *complex* values, you'd have to

- use the regex once for the real, once for the imaginary part
- append `[ij]{1}` to the imaginary part (only lower case)
- take care of spacing (`\s*`) and a `[+-]{1}` in between the two parts
- take care of the fact that the imaginary part may appear alone, but the real part may not appear with a trailing `[+-]{1}`, but no imaginary part.

Comment: Is this regex is in a file we can consult?

Comment: @Etienne: no; I made it up, with a little help. I added a reference to my sourcem and re-worded the answer such that there is a bit more room for error ^_^

Comment: I've verified what you've written for (real-valued) floats. I didn't find any other examples with the possible exception of `x=false`, which is presumably handled via a cast and therefore isn't quite fair.

Comment: I don't understand this part of your regex: `([eEdD]?)(?(2)[+-]?[0-9]+)$`. I would write `([eEdD][+-]?[0-9]+)?` for that bit. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: no need; your version is superior. I'll edit it in.

Comment: I would expect that a float can contain at most a single sign at the beginning and that any possible extra plus or minus signs should be considered as unary operators. In [Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals), the leading sign is not even considered to be part of the number.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Well, the sign bit is part of [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), so somewhere you'd indeed expect at least one sign to be part of the string itself, beit explicit or not. I think you're right; if I were to implement a `double` class, I would also interpret *all* leading sign symbols simply as unary operators...oh well.